# How to install Mongodb C# driver via Terminal on Mac OS

Tags: c#, mongodb, terminal, nuget-package

I would like to install [Mongodb C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) on the server from client side. Therefore, I have to use Terminal for the installation. I tried to manually download the .nupkg file but I can't install it.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

**update**

Now I use `nuget install mongoDB.Driver` and `nuget install mongocsharpdriver`

and I got

`Successfully installed 'mongocsharpdriver 2.5.0' to /Users/my/project/path`

but when I try to use `mcs Program.cs`

I still got this error

```
Program.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Program.cs(54,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ObjectId' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this? 
I don't know why the 'MongoDB' could not be found.

my program.cs is like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
namespace testMongo
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("uesr");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to tunnel your connection over ssh?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm sorry. This is my first time for ssh command. I use `ssh servername` and want to install Mongodb C# driver on the server.

Comment: Usually, you install and / or compile the driver  on the client side... Please specify exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg My problem is I want to compile my C# code that connects with mongodb on the client side. I have already install C# compiler and it works. But when I try to run the code that connected with mongodb on client side, it said `The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`  So I think I have to install MongoDB C# driver on the server.